BlenderKit material not exporting right
I downloaded a material from BlednerKit addon. However after exporting it into various formats and putting them inside unity, or opening them with the default windows 3d Viewer, the material looks completely different.
I have unwrapped the textures in blender
This could be a problem outside of blender, but seeing that is broken both in the Viewer and in unity, i decided to ask here.


How can i fix this so the sphere looks the same in Unity as in blender?

Have you created a material in Unity with the textures assigned? Materials rarely translate 1:1 from application to application.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Chances are that it is impossible to export the way you wish. We need to see the shader node setup. Or can you share the file https://blend-exchange.com/?
